# javascript set "this" for method added to a class

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

is it possible to define the this parameter for methods if they are added afterwards?
So I would like to set **this** to a specific value. If I add a method to the object afterwards like this obj.prototype.methodName = ... I would like this to also be this specified value. Is that possible without adding the method using bind?

Comment: using `call()` or `apply()`? `foo.methodName.call(xxx);`

Comment: Yeah, I would like not not use any of those, but just foo.methodName()

Comment: You want [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)?

Comment: Ahh, no I would like to know if I can say that every method, that is added to obj will be called with this set to e.g. "foo". Even though I call the new method like this `obj.newMethod();` and add it to the object like this `obj.newMethod = function(){}` I guess its just not possible.

Comment: Yes, it is called bind, call, apply. You need to use them or you need to initialize your objects from the start to have the scope you want. Maybe if you showed a sample of what you are actually trying to achieve, someone could give you better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ['call()'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and ['apply()'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) functions

```
function add (a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

// Outputs: 3
console.log(add.call(this, 1, 2));

// Outputs: 3
console.log(add.apply(this, [1, 2]));
```

You can find more information about it [Invoking JavaScript Functions With 'call' and 'apply'](http://us6.campaign-archive2.com/?u=2cc20705b76fa66ab84a6634f&id=53178479fc)

Comment: Here's a much better article about [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) from MDN which goes into a good explanation of what `this` is in various contexts and how to change it.